# Pyhon Check if all the items in list can be numeric

Tags: python, list

Lets say i have this in python:

```
List1 = ["643", "53", "531"]
```

and I want to check if all the items in my list can be digits (isDigit), how do I do it without using a for loop, and most preferably with the all() function.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Why don't you want to use a ``for`` loop, and does this include comprehensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, thats possible try this:

It uses `all()` and a `generator expression`

Basically it makes a list out of bools and then checks if all bools are True.

```
List1 = ["643", "53", "531"]
all(n.isdigit() for n in List1)
```

Comment: This does not use a list comprehension, but a generator expression.

Comment: I ran it, and there's no error, but I tried it with this list: List1 = ["5", "k3", "d"] and it returned True for some reason.

Comment: It should be ``n.isdigit()``, not ``n.isdigit``.

Comment: You need to use `all(n.isdigit() for n in List1)`, otherwise it will always return true since `n.isdigit()` returns `built-in method`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [map](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) function-

```
List1 = ["643", "53", "531"]
all(map(str.isdigit, List1))
```

Output-

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

List1 = ["643", "53", "531"]
print(np.char.isdigit(np.array(List1)))
```